# How to refresh the task in a retained TaskFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-task

I have used a `Fragment` to perform the background update of the app avoiding interruption if the activity is destroyed or paused.

Following [this sample](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)

the update task start in

```
if (mTaskFragment == null) {
      mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
      fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }
```

and works fine.

My problem is that I want to allow the user to update the data using a `Button updateButton` but I haven't clear how could tell the TaskFragment to update again its task (e.g. the `DummyTask` in the linked sample).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a method to the TaskFragment to handle the data update, and when the button is clicked, simply trigger it

For example, add this method to the fragment

```
public void updateData(SomeParams ... params){
//do something
}
```

then in the activity for the given button add a click listener

and in it trigger `mTaskFragment.updateData(zParams);`

Comment: Often the solution is very simple but you cannot see it. Thanks a lot!